# What should i select for my mobile applciation development? Native way or cordova or react,Node.js like things

Tags: android, ios, node.js, cordova, reactjs

I want to develop application in android and iOS both.
But i am confuse between native development and development using react and node.js etc.
Please help me to choose (If possible specify reason).
P.S Here cost is not an issue.

Comment: Is there a language preference (i.e. are you already skilled in a specific language which you would like to write in)?

Comment: yes i am android(JAVA) developer

Comment: You can decide on basis of your requirement. If you will use phonegap it will not great in permofomance as comprative to Native. BUt phonegap application you can port to different platform with very less effort. So you have to decide what you want.

Comment: I would recommend Native development. For the sheer control over the UI elements you'll have. If your app becomes popular you will want to beable to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need high performance and attractive UI and don't want to be blocked by some functionalities that may not br provided by cross platform, I recommend you to use native platform. But if your app doesn't need to be very attractive and doesn't need too much processing, then you can use cross-platform. Actually for many features you need to add plugins if you are building cross platform app and adding number of plugins makes your application slower.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well there isn't much data to go on, but there are several options if you want to write cross platform apps.

There is:

- [Sencha Touch](https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/#overview) - HTML and JavaScript
- [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/about/) - HTML, JavaScript and CSS
- [QT](http://www.qt.io/mobile-app-development/) - C++ and QML
- [Appmethod](http://www.appmethod.com/features) - C++ and Object Pascal
- [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/platform) - C#
- [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/mobile-app-development-vs.aspx) - looks like you can do C# or C++, or Unity for games.

and  probably a lot more...

Why would you choose one of these instead of writing in the native language for the platform?

Well, the pros seem to outweigh the cons. If you are targeting several platforms, I would choose one of the options above, simply because you only have to write everything once. If you did it native for each platform, you would write everything twice or maybe three or even four times. Using one of the above tools will be much easier and save you time, and they might be just as seamless and workable as native development.

To simply answer your question, If you would like to be able to write your app once, and be able to manage all future updates by managing only one code base, do cross platform using one of the above tools. The only downside is that you might have to learn a new language (but with a place like Stack Overflow, learning new languages is pretty awesome). It will save you time in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,But my main concern is which platform should i select native or cross-platform.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you do cross platform, you can have it go to Android, iOS, Windows and maybe even BlackBerry devices. If you do native, you would only be able to export to the platform you developed for. If you only want it to be for android, stay native Java. If you want to get it out all over the place, using one of the above tools will make life easier.